# Traverse/sequence an Array<Either<E, A>> into Either<Array<E>, Array<A>> in fp-ts

Tags: functional-programming, applicative, either, fp-ts

I have a list of entities where even one failed validation would yield an error. However, I'd still like to iterate the whole list and collect all the errors for further logging.

Traverse/sequence with a default Either's Applicative would yield `Either<E, A[]>` (only the first encountered error) instead of needed `Either<E[], A[]>`.

Is there a default tool in the library to achieve this, or could it be achieved by writing a custom Applicative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no fp-ts function that does this directly, but you could use [`getApplicativeValidation`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Either.ts.html#getapplicativevalidation) from the `Either` module:

```ts
import * as E from 'fp-ts/lib/Either'
import * as RA from 'fp-ts/lib/ReadonlyArray'
import {pipe} from 'fp-ts/lib/function'

const collectErrors = <E, A>(
  xs: readonly E.Either<E, A>[]
): E.Either<readonly E[], readonly A[]> =>
  pipe(
    xs,
    RA.traverse(E.getApplicativeValidation(RA.getSemigroup<E>()))(
      E.mapLeft(RA.of)
    )
  )

// Left(['a', 'b'])
collectErrors([E.left('a'), E.right(1), E.left('b'))])
// Right([1, 2])
collectErrors([E.right(1), E.right(2)])
// Right([])
collectErrors([])
```

How this works is that `getApplicativeValidation` takes a `Semigroup` instance and returns an `Applicative` instance that can be used with `traverse`. The applicative instance will combine errors using the semigroup instance.

```ts
RA.traverse(
  // The applicative instance for the either that will collect the errors 
  // into an array
  E.getApplicativeValidation(
    // The semigroup instance for readonly E[], which concatenates the arrays
    RA.getSemigroup<E>()
  )
)(
  // Turn each Either<E, A> into Either<readonly E[], A> by putting each error
  // inside an array so they can be concatenated
  E.mapLeft(RA.of)
)
```